# renamed Main.java but still exists as a Run option in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I created a `Java` project in `intelliJ`, it comes with a default `Main.java`. I then renamed `Main.java` to some other name, and also changed then class name to the same name.

Now the problem is, `Main` still exists as a `Run` option (also in the `Configuration`) with a red cross on it. I am wondering how to remove it and why it would happen?

Also where does `intelliJ` really shine? It seems it has some inconveniences here and there to me.

Comment: To remove it, edit your run config and delete it. About your opinion about intellij, thanks for sharing it...

Comment: @RC. it happens sometimes that a red wave line underneath project, file name etc in the project view, what is going on?

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `edit configurations` which should bring you to a screen like this:

[image]

where you can find the bad `Main.java` configuration and click the minus button. (Shown in gray in the image)